# declare a boolean variable then assign an expression

Tags: java, variables, initialization, boolean, expression

So I am very new to Java. Booleans are giving me an issue because I seem to just not be grasping something. Here is an example. I feel like if I can grasp this example then I can grasp Booleans altogether.

Declare a boolean variable (call it *scout*) and intitialize to false; then assign the expression **'A' < 'a'** to variable *scout*; and finally print out the value of variable *scout* with this label. *Scout* =

So I understand declaring the boolean variable,

**boolean *scout* = false;**

but thats as far as I get. Can someone dumb this down for me so I can understand it please?

Comment: `scout = 'A' < 'a'` like this?

Answer (score 0):

So here's the thing when you use `>`  and `<` the variables are converted into int. which means there ASCII values. [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/)
now for `A` ASCII value is 65 and for `a` ASCII value is 97. So the actual comparing is between `65 < 97`which is true so it prints true as result.

```
boolean scount= 'A'<'a';
    System.out.println(scount);
```